# Concatenate file contents AND names

Tags: scripting, find, pipe, cat, markdown

I've been writing for many months. The files I create are dated files named like `2011-06-13.markdown` with daily content. I've decided I want to have all the writing in one file instead but I'd like entries to be in reverse chronological order with a header of the date (from the filename). Meaning I'd like a directory of separate files like these three:

`2014-09-21.markdown`

> Look at all these words I've written!

`2014-09-22.markdown`

> That's one serious writing habit I have!

`2014-09-23.markdown`

> Asked question on stackexchange. Damn that is a helpful community!

to end up looking like one file like this:

`writing.markdown`

> ## 2014-09-23
>
> Asked question on stackexchange. Damn that is a helpful community!
>
> ## 2014-09-22
>
> That's one serious writing habit I have!
>
> ## 2014-09-21
>
> Look at all these words I've written!

All the files are in one directory, and named correctly. I suspect some combination of `find` and `cat` can help me, but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do what you want with a single file (which we'll call `$file` for now) and print it to standard output

```bsh
# prepend a "# " and remove the .markdown from the filename
sed 's/\.markdown//' <<< "# $file"
# print a blank line
echo
# output the file
cat "$file"
```

Now for what you really wanted, enclose that in a `for` loop to iterate over every markdown in the directory. Then output the result to a file.

```bsh
for file in *.markdown; do
    # prepend a "# " and remove the .markdown from the filename
    sed 's/\.markdown//' <<< "# $file"
    # print a blank line
    echo
    # output the file
    cat "$file"
    # separate the files with another blank line
    echo
done > writing.markdown
```

EDIT: Wait, that's not what you wanted! To reverse the order, we can use the `find` commmand to find all markdown files, then pipe the output into `sort -r` to get the reverse sort order you wanted. Finally, pipe that into `read` and loop. Additionally, we'll need to invoke `basename` when extracting the date from the filename since `find` returns a path rather than a filename.

```bsh
find -name '*.markdown' -not -name 'writing.markdown' | sort -r | while read file; do
    # prepend a "# " and remove the .markdown from the filename
    sed 's/\.markdown//' <<< "# $(basename $file)"
    # print a blank line
    echo
    # output the file
    cat "$file"
    # separate the files with another blank line
    echo
done > writing.markdown
```

Since they're really hard to google for, I'm including a link to some documentation on [Here Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) in case you're not familiar with them.

Comment: This seemed like it was working at first and then I got `cat: stdout: No space left on device
-bash: echo: write error: No space left on device` For reference there are only 136kb across 129 files.

Comment: Oops! I just tried it myself and got the error `cat: ./writing.markdown: input file is output file`. Not the same error as you, but tells me that the issue is that the script is trying to read and write from `writing.markdown`. This can be avoided by changing the `find` command to `find -name '*.markdown' -not -name 'writing.markdown'`. I'll edit my post to correct this.

Comment: This is great! I got an error on the `-not -name` so I just dropped that part and wrote to `writing.txt` instead. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this. I have written into three text files `sample1`, `sample2`, and `sample3` with the exact contents that you have provided. When I type this command:

`cat sample1 sample2 sample3 >> sample4`

I get this for results when I `cat sample4`:

```
2014-09-23
Asked question on stackexchange. Damn that is a helpful community!
2014-09-22.markdown
That's one serious writing habit I have!
2014-09-21.markdown
Look at all these words I've written!
```

The `>>` appends to `sample4`, whereas a single `>` would overwrite `sample4` each time it is used. So in your case, you can use this command:

`cat 2014-09-23.markdown 2014-09-22.markdown 2014-09-21.markdown >> writing.markdown`

Comment: This method isn't giving me file names, just file contents.